# OpenCV persistent object tracking and hysteresis strategy

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm building an object tracking API for my team.

My code will recognize foreground objects in the camera scene. Over time, it will call methods for `addObject(id, pos)`, `updateObject(id, newPos)`, and `removeObject(id)` on instances that implement my listener interface. These are post frame-processing events -- so they might occur 30 times a second.

How can I make sure that objects don't flicker in and out of existence? I need to give objects a minimum lifetime. If an object disappears for one frame and reappears in the same spot in the next frame with a new ID, that is also undesired flickering.

---

(My thoughts so far) I have thought about using an object mask accumulator as a basis for  instantiation. I imagine a grayscale image, where candidate regions for objects would be intensified in the accumulator each frame, then as soon as an object region exceeds a threshold, it gets instantiated and we call the `addObject(id, pos)` method. Now, the problem with this is, an object can hover around the threshold in the accumulator and can still exhibit flickery behavior.  So then, I would add some constant value to the object region as soon as it is instantiated so that it would have a lifetime in the accumulator. This constant would be subtracted when the region crosses below the accumulator threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution described in my question, almost without any further tweaks. It worked well for what I was doing. It is necessary to keep a copy of the previous accumulator state, though, to determine whether the pixel values are rising or falling across the threshold value.